# Are optics (or lenses) useful abstractions in Mathematics?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, computer-science

Optics are a set of categorical constructions that are widely used in functional programming to handle deeply nested substructures. In some way, optics offer a principled method to compose substructures (including isomorphisms). For a more detailed explanation, see Bartosz Milewski's blog post [Optics for the Working Mathematician](https://bartoszmilewski.com/2021/09/08/optics-for-the-working-mathematician/).

Given the prevalent significance of substructures in Mathematics, are optics useful abstraction for Mathematics? Is there some problem can be better understood using them, or is there a proof that can be simplified using them?

Comment: Is it just a pun, or is there actually a connection?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the mathematical structure underlying profunctor optics is quite subtle and interesting per se: https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.07488

The notion of Tambara module arose in the theory of monoidal categories for purposes that were completely motivated by pure mathematics.

Comment: Why the downvote? Perhaps I should have answered with another pun on lens spaces instead.